# jQuery click event not showing and hiding input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I want to show the custom link input if the user clicks on the radio button else it should be hidden. but it doesn't work. any idea why? thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#customLinkRadio").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").show('fade');
    });

    $("#defaultPaymentMethodRadio").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").hide('fade');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="button_text" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Payment Method</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
          <input type="radio" id="default" name="payment_method" id="defaultPaymentMethodRadio" class="custom-control-input">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="default">Default</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
          <input type="radio" id="custom_link" name="payment_method" id="customLinkRadio" class="custom-control-input">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="custom_link">Custom Link</label>
      </div>
      <input type="url" name="custom_url" placeholder="https://www.yourlink.com" id="customLink" class="form-control mt-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check again.

Comment: You can achieve by css only there is no need js or jquery.

Comment: @AlokMali okay, let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `id` attribute in your radio inputs. That's why these are not working.

Please remove and check again.

See below example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#customLink").hide();
    $("#customLinkRadio").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").show('fade');
    });

    $("#defaultPaymentMethodRadio").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").hide('fade');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="button_text" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Payment Method</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="defaultPaymentMethodRadio" class="custom-control-input">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultPaymentMethodRadio">Default</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="customLinkRadio" class="custom-control-input">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="customLinkRadio">Custom Link</label>
        </div>
        <input type="url" name="custom_url" placeholder="https://www.yourlink.com" id="customLink" class="form-control mt-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I can't select radio buttons with your code.

Comment: I did, still can't select radio buttons

Comment: I have changed `for` for both radios. Did you change it?

Comment: @lachiweb, Take it, easy bro. If Mamun answered it first, You should approve his answer. It's not a big deal.

Comment: But I realized his code is not updated. it'll not work for future users. that's why I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Though multiple *id* attribute in an HTML element will not through any error, it may lead you to some unexpected results as *id*'s after the first one will be ignored silently. Thus when you will reference them (attributes after the first one) in your code, your code will certainly fail.**

You have multiple *id* attribute set to radio buttons. As the *id* attribute must be unique in a document and first id's does not match to the ones, thus you are using in the script your code unable to hide/show.

Remove the wrong id's from the radio buttons.

**Update:** Changes made to the *lable* element's *for* attribute by matching the radio button's *id* to accommodate with bootstrap:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#customLinkRadio").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").show('fade');
    });

    $("#defaultPaymentMethodRadio").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").hide('fade');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="button_text" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Payment Method</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="defaultPaymentMethodRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultPaymentMethodRadio">Default</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="customLinkRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customLinkRadio">Custom Link</label>
        </div>
        <input type="url" name="custom_url" placeholder="https://www.yourlink.com" id="customLink" class="form-control mt-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the other *id*'s:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#custom_link").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").show('fade');
    });

    $("#default").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").hide('fade');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="button_text" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Payment Method</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
          <input type="radio" id="default" name="payment_method" class="custom-control-input">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="default">Default</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
          <input type="radio" id="custom_link" name="payment_method" class="custom-control-input">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="custom_link">Custom Link</label>
      </div>
      <input type="url" name="custom_url" placeholder="https://www.yourlink.com" id="customLink" class="form-control mt-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't select them

Comment: @lachiweb, is it in the answer I have provided?

Comment: @lachiweb, I have tested both in *chrome* and *firefox* and found working as expected:)

Comment: It should be working. I thinking there's something wrong with bootstrap I don't know.. I'm using bootstrap custom form inputs.

Comment: @lachiweb, the code is straight forward here. May be there is some conflicting code in your development environment, you should check that, best of luck:)

Comment: @lachiweb, though I am not sure but you can try using the others id's like I did in the second example in the updated answer, please check:)

Comment: I've found out that in the bootstrap custom radio button. the `id` and label `for` should be the same. that's why the buttons were not working.  thank you for your quick answer :)

Comment: @lachiweb, any explanation would be grate for unaccepting the answer:)

Comment: Your code is not updated. it'll not work for future users. you should match the `id` of the radio input and label `for`. even though you answered first but still the bootstrap code doesn't work. sorry.

Comment: @lachiweb, so the issue is the bootstrap and there is not a single hint on that in the question, really strange!!!

Comment: !'m sorry. but I gave you an upvote. thanks again for your quick answer.

Comment: second answer? there are some many answers. I didn't notice that one. I thought your answer is the first one. which don't works.

Comment: I really feel bad right now. I know you answered first. and I unaccepted your answer. I didn't saw your second answer

Comment: Like I have said. there are so many answers. I missed your second answer. sorry about that and when you added the second answer my issue was already fixed that's why I didn't check it.

Answer (score 1):

You should only have to try `show` and `hide` also remove multiple `Id's` from element. You are having multiple `ids` `default` and `custom_link`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#customLinkRadio").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").show(500);
    });

    $("#defaultPaymentMethodRadio").click(function(){
        $("#customLink").hide(500);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="button_text" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Payment Method</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="payment_method" id="defaultPaymentMethodRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="default">Default</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio"  name="payment_method" id="customLinkRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="custom_link">Custom Link</label>
        </div>
        <input type="url" name="custom_url" placeholder="https://www.yourlink.com" id="customLink" class="form-control mt-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: same, now I can't select the radio buttons.

Comment: It works here. but not in my codebase. I'm using bootstrap custom forms.

Comment: see the `console` for errors there might be some other issues

Comment: remove those duplicate id's copy paste html and js from answer

Comment: I did use your code. if I remove the second id I can't select the radio button.

Comment: remove  `id="default"` and `id="custom_link" `

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use `.change()` event instead of click, since you are checking for radio button, you have to get the radio button value and check against which option is selected, **note** that I added value to your radio buttons in my snippet and the main issue is as mentioned in other answers is in your HTML tags ids which.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#customLink").hide()
  $("input[name='payment_method']").change(function(){
       $(this).val() == 2 ? $("#customLink").show() : $("#customLink").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="button_text" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Payment Method</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="default" checked name="payment_method" id="defaultPaymentMethodRadio" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="default">Default</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="custom_link" name="payment_method" id="customLinkRadio" class="custom-control-input" value="2">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="custom_link">Custom Link</label>
        </div>
        <input type="url" name="custom_url" placeholder="https://www.yourlink.com" id="customLink" class="form-control mt-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='payment_method']").click(function(){
       if($(this).val() == "customLinkRadio"){
           $("#customLink").show("fade")
       }
       else if($(this).val() == "defaultPaymentMethodRadio")
       {
           $("#customLink").hide("fade");
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="button_text" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Payment Method</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="defaultPaymentMethodRadio" id="defaultPaymentMethodRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultPaymentMethodRadio">Default</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" checked name="payment_method" value="customLinkRadio" id="customLinkRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customLinkRadio">Custom Link</label>
        </div>
        <input type="url" name="custom_url" placeholder="https://www.yourlink.com" id="customLink" class="form-control mt-2">
    </div>
</div>
```